# handler function passing variable google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is any way I can have the user click a button, and, with this click of the button, change a local variable. For example:

```
var email = “";
var button1 = app.createButton("Yes").setId("button1”);
```

I want to find out if there is anyway that I can change the variable ‘email’ if the user clicks the “Yes” button. I was thinking that I could use a ServerHandler function, but I couldn’t find a way to change the local variable “email” in the server handler function (do i pass it to the function, make “email” global, etc.). Also, would that variable “email” be passed by value? What I mean is, once the ServerHandler was called, and that function was run, would the variable “email” be changed in the caller function?

Comment: Deprecated. The UI service was deprecated on December 11, 2014. To create user interfaces, use the HTML service instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your button just needs an event handler, and anything that happens inside the event can modify running code.  In the below case, this is all stored in the variable email.

### html

```
<button id='btn'>
  Click me!
</button>

<div id='email'>
</div>
```

### js

```
let email;
$('#btn').on('click', changevar)
function changevar(){
    email = 'some email address';
    $('#email').text(email);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8ek62u65/3/